Highly-efficient $n(n+1)$?
Appendix G of this paper provides a highly-efficient way of squaring integer numbers. (LMK if anything more advanced is already available.) I'm wondering if this approach can be easily modified to calculate $n(n+m)$ for some fixed $m$? I am particularly interested in the $n(n+1)$ case.
